# Updating part of a wider integer through a uint8_t reference

Tags: c++, casting, reference, language-lawyer, cpu-registers

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>


struct Registers {
    Registers() : af(0),
    f(*(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&af))),
    a(*(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&af) + 1)) {

    }
    std::uint16_t af;
    std::uint8_t& f;
    std::uint8_t& a;  
};

int main() {
    Registers r;
    r.af = 0x00FF;
    r.a = 0xAA;
    std::printf("AF: %04X A: %02X F: %02X\n", r.af, r.a, r.f);
    return 0;
}
```

Regardless of endianness issues, is this legal c++, or does it invoke some type of undefined behavior? I think this should be fine with pointers and does not violate strict aliasing, since uint8_t is a char type, but I am not sure if this is legal through references.

This seems to work fine with most compiler flags turned on and does not throw any warnings:

```
$ clang++ reg.cpp -O3 -fsanitize=undefined -fstrict-aliasing -Wall && ./a.out
AF: AAFF A: AA F: FF
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is okay as long as `uint8_t` is a typedef of `unsigned char`, which I don't think is required but I'm not sure what other type could be used.

Comment: Which is the most significant register? `f`?

Comment: IMO it is legal although I have seen people make arguments along the lines that the standard doesn't technically guarantee the result of the pointer cast points to the same object . (I don't buy those arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noted in your question, the fact that you are casting to a "byte" type almost certainly removes any issues of violating strict aliasing requirements.

Nevertheless, from a strict, "language-lawyer" perspective, the `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&af) + 1` expression *potentially* invokes undefined behaviour – because the pointer operand is **not** the address of an array element, and array elements are the **only** types on which such pointer arithmetic is well-defined by the Standard.

From [this Draft C++17 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) (bold emphasis mine):

> ##### 8.5.6 Additive operators       [expr.add]
>
> …
> <sup>4</sup>     When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a
> pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. ***If the expression P points to element x[*i*] of an array object x with *n* elements***
> the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value *j*) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) element x[*i + j*] if 0 ≤ *i + j* ≤
> *n*; ***otherwise, the behavior is undefined.*** Likewise, the expression P -
> J points to the (possibly-hypothetical) element x[*i − j*] if 0 ≤ *i − j*
> ≤ *n*; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

However, whether or not it is legal and well-defined to consider a `uint16_t` variable as an array of (two) `uint8_t` elements is where there may be room for debate.

---

**Notes/Discussion**

After some very helpful comments, I am now (even more) convinced that, even though there may *formally* be undefined behaviour in the pointer addition expression, there is no situation (at least, on any sane platform) where the code presented in the original question will not work as intended.

First, as pointed out by Chris Dodd, §6.7 (paragraph 2) of the above-quoted Draft Standard has this:

> <sup>2</sup>    For any object (other than a base-class
> subobject) of trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object
> holds a valid value of type T, the underlying bytes (6.6.1) making up
> the object can be copied into an array of `char`, `unsigned char`, or
> `std::byte`. If the content of that array is copied back into the
> object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value.

This confirms that the `uint16_t` data *can* be treated – at least, in terms of its memory layout – as a 2-element array of `uint8_t` data.

Second, as pointed out by Language Lawyer, an object of non-array type can be considered an array of a single element; further, pointer arithmetic on the address of such an object is *allowed* to result in the address of the "one-pass-the-end" hypothetical element. From a [slightly later Draft Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.compound#3.sentence-12) **(§6.8.3) [basic.compund]**:

> <sup>3.4</sup>     For purposes of pointer arithmetic ([expr.add]) and comparison
> ([expr.rel], [expr.eq]), a pointer past the end of the last element of
> an array x of n elements is considered to be equivalent to a pointer
> to a hypothetical array element n of x and an object of type T that is
> not an array element is considered to belong to an array with one
> element of type T.

Thus, combining the above two, the hypothetical "one-pass-the-end" `uint8_t` element referenced by the result of the pointer addition ***will*** be the second byte of the `uint16_t` data object.

Comment: Section 6.7 of that draft certainly suggests that any object of a *trivially copyable* type can be treated as an array of sizeof(T) `char` objects, and I'm pretty certain that uint16_t meets the requirements of trivially copyable.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I agree. However, 6.7 (para #2) only says that the component bytes can be copied into an array and back again - not that the object itself can be treated as an array, in terms of pointer arithmetic. I guess I'm being overly pedantic, though.

Comment: _because the pointer operand is not the address of an array element_ [For purposes of pointer arithmetic … an object of type `T` that is not an array element is considered to belong to an array with one element of type `T`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.compound#3.sentence-12)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Hmm. OK - it's the middle of the night, here, but I'll try editing some more details (and/or better terminology) into the answer tomorrow. However, if the pointed-to `uint8_t` is a 1-element array, then **using** the "address + 1" value is also undefined behaviour.

Comment: _the pointed-to `uint8_t`_ The pointed-to object is of `uint16_t` type. _**using** the "address + 1" value is also undefined behaviour_ Merely **adding** 1 (even 0) is undefined behavior.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The pointer is cast to a `uint8_t*` **before** the addition operation.

Comment: _The pointer is cast to a `uint8_t*`_ How does it affect which object is pointed to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240365/discussion-between-adrian-mole-and-language-lawyer).

Comment: _This confirms that the `uint16_t` data can be treated – at least, in terms of its memory layout – as a 2-element array of `uint8_t` data_ How the fact that bytes can be copied from an object to some array confirm that the object itself can be treated as array? _Thus, combining the above two, the hypothetical "one-pass-the-end" `uint8_t` element_  one-past-the-end of what? You don't even have a `uint8_t` element.